# how to fix XLConnect loading issue as each time i try to load it i get this message

Tags: r

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘XLConnect’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
lazy-load database 'C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rJava/R/rJava.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning message:
In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1